# Checkbox toggle to create string concatenation or make variable blank

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function where if the checkbox is unchecked then the variable will become blank. If it is checked then the variable will take the input and concatenate it with some text.

I keep getting the input value instead of a blank variable.

```js
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("fabric").value;
    var check = document.getElementById("check");
    if (input.trim() =='' || check.checked == true){
    input == '';
    } else {
    input = 'Fabric: ' + document.getElementById("fabric").value;
    }
    console.log(input)
    }
    </script>
```

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check">Test</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <td><input id="fabric" placeholder="Input"></td>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can simplify a bit. You probably also intend to use `=` instead of `==`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("fabric").value;
  var check = document.getElementById("check");
  if (check.checked !== true) {
    input = '';
  } else {
    input = 'Fabric: ' + document.getElementById("fabric").value;
  }
  console.log(input)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check">Test</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <input id="fabric" placeholder="Input">
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```